# Can I connect an external (R) process to each pyspark worker during setup

Tags: python, r, apache-spark, pyspark, rpy2

I want to have each python worker start an R shell using rpy2. Can I do this during some sort of setup phase similar to how I assume this would happen when you import a Python module to be used for later executor tasks? For example:

```
import numpy as np

df.mapPartitions(lambda x: np.zeros(x))
```

In my case I want to instead start an R shell on each executor and import R libraries, which would look something like this:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from  rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rlibrary = importr('testrlibrary')

df.mapPartitions(lambda x: rlibrary.rfunc(x))
```

But I don't want this to occur inside the call to `mapPartitions`, because then it would happen at the task-level as opposed to once per executor core. That approach works and looks more like the example below but is not useful for me.

```
def model(partition):
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    from  rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
    rlibrary = importr('testrlibrary')
    rlibrary.rfunc(partition)

df.mapPartitions(model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work just fine:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from  rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

def length_(s):
    stringi = importr("stringi")  
    return stringi.stri_length(s)[0]

sc.parallelize(["foo", "bar", "foobar"]).map(length_)
```

[`R` object](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/fe7b154143bcc0316a036f2fef85cea90b2963ec/rpy/robjects/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-302), which represents R interpreter, [is a singleton](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/fe7b154143bcc0316a036f2fef85cea90b2963ec/rpy/robjects/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-347) so it will be initialized only once and R doesn't re-import already attached libraries. There is some overhead from calling `require` multiple times but it should be negligible compared to the cost of passing your data to and from R.

If you want something more sophisticated you can create your own [singleton module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10936709/1560062) or use [Borg pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1318406/1560062) to handle imports but it could be an overkill.

> I assume this would happen when you import a python module to be used for later executor tasks

It actually depends on a configuration. By default Spark reuses interpreters between tasks but this behavior can be modified.

I've provided some examples as an answer to [In Apache spark, what is the difference between using mapPartitions and combine use of broadcast variable and map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34501334/1560062). Maybe you'll find these useful.

Comment: See the related question here: [How can I partition pyspark RDDs holding R functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669751/)