# How can I partition pyspark RDDs holding R functions

Tags: python, r, apache-spark, pyspark, rpy2

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

dffunc = sc.parallelize([(0,robjects.r.rnorm),(1,robjects.r.runif)])
dffunc.collect()
```

Outputs

```
[(0, <rpy2.rinterface.SexpClosure - Python:0x7f2ecfc28618 / R:0x26abd18>), (1, <rpy2.rinterface.SexpClosure - Python:0x7f2ecfc283d8 / R:0x26aad28>)]
```

While the partitioned version results in an error:

```
dffuncpart = dffunc.partitionBy(2)
dffuncpart.collect()
```

---

```
RuntimeError: ('R cannot evaluate code before being initialized.', <built-in function unserialize>
```

It seems like this error is that `R` wasn't loaded on one of the partitions, which I assume implies that the first import step was not performed. Is there anyway around this?

**EDIT 1** This second example causes me to think there's a bug in the timing of pyspark or rpy2.

```
dffunc = sc.parallelize([(0,robjects.r.rnorm),     (1,robjects.r.runif)]).partitionBy(2)
def loadmodel(model):
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    return model[1](2)
dffunc.map(loadmodel).collect()
```

Produces the same error R cannot evaluate code before being initialized.

```
dffuncpickle = sc.parallelize([(0,pickle.dumps(robjects.r.rnorm)),(1,pickle.dumps(robjects.r.runif))]).partitionBy(2)
def loadmodelpickle(model):
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    import pickle
    return pickle.loads(model[1])(2)
dffuncpickle.map(loadmodelpickle).collect()
```

Works just as expected.

Comment: I think that problem is more subtle. You need an active R session where data is unpickled. It may or may not be true depending on a timing. Personally I would avoid passing R objects / or views over R objects around.

Comment: @zero323 Perhaps I can combine the use of python pickling in memory - `pickle.dumps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to say that "this is not a bug in rpy2, this is a feature" but I'll  realistically have to settle with "this is a limitation".

What is happening is that rpy2 has 2 [interface levels](http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/overview.html#design-notes). One is a low-level one (closer to R's C API) and available through `rpy2.rinterface` and the other one is a high-level interface with more bells and whistles, more "pythonic", and with classes for R objects inheriting from `rinterface` level-ones (that last part is important for the part about pickling below). Importing the high-level interface results in initializing (starting) the embedded R with default parameters if necessary. Importing the low-level interface `rinterface` does not have this side effect and the initialization of the embedded R must be performed explicitly (function `initr`). rpy2 was designed this way because the initialization of the embedded R can have parameters: importing first `rpy2.rinterface`, setting the initialization, then importing `rpy2.robjects` makes this possible.

In addition to that the serialization (pickling) of R objects wrapped by rpy2 is currently only defined at the `rinterface` level (see the [documentation](http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/robjects_serialization.html)). Pickling `robjects`-level (high-level) rpy2 objects is using the `rinterface`-level code and when unpickling them they will remain at that lower-level (the Python pickle contains the module the class of the object is defined in and will import that module - here `rinterface`, which does not imply the initialization of the embedded R). The reason for things being this way are simply that it was "good enough for now": at the time this was implemented I had to simultaneously think of a good way to bridge two somewhat different languages and learn my way through Python C-API and pickling/unpickling Python objects. Given the ease with which one can write something like

```
import rpy2.robjects
```

or

```
import rpy2.rinterface
rpy2.rinterface.initr()
```

before unpickling, this was never revisited. The uses of rpy2's pickling I know about are using Python's `multiprocessing` (and adding something similar to the import statements in the code initializing a child process  was a cheap and sufficient fix). May this is the time to look at this again. File a bug report for rpy2 if the case.

**edit:** this is undoubtedly an issue with rpy2. pickled `robjects`-level objects should unpickle back to `robjects`-level, not `rinterface`-level. I have opened an [issue in the rpy2 tracker](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/324/unpickling-robjects-level-objects-returns) (and already pushed a rudimentary patch in the default/dev branch).

**2nd edit:** The patch is part of released rpy2 starting with version 2.7.7 (latest release at the time of writing is 2.7.8).

Comment: Thanks for the superb explanation. I don't quite follow the critical last bit: `and adding an import, or calling rinterface.initr() was a cheap and sufficient fix`. What import are you referring to? Lastly, in which case should I file a bug report?

Comment: That part was not the clearest, as you note it. I edited it in the hope to improve it. This is what is happening with your function `loadmodelpickle`.

Comment: This patch works like a charm. Looking forward to the next release, thanks and great work on the package, the documentation is great.